# How to get all GET request values in Django Views?

Tags: python, django, django-views, get, url-parameters

There are lots of question discussing how to get 1 parameter, but how do you get all of the parameters, preserving their order?

There's this way: `request.GET.get('q', '')` to get 1 parameter.

I need to capture POST requests to my URL, then add a parameter to the URL, and send it right back to confirm it's validity and source. This is for PayPal IPN if you're wondering.

Thanks!

Comment: Order is not significant in post or get requests.

Comment: Yes it is, read PayPal IPN documentation.

Answer (score 5):

As @Daniel Roseman said you probably don't need to preserve the order, in which case you can just use the `request.GET` dict

Alternatively you can get the raw querystring:

```
request.META['QUERY_STRING']
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Answer (score 1):

As [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) mentions, order should not be significant between POST or GET request parameters; think of them like `key`-`value` pairs rather than a list.

If you want to maintain order, then perhaps pass a list as the `value` in your `POST` and grab it in Django:

```
myData = request.POST.get("myQuery")
```

Specifically, **POST requests don't use the querystring*** ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not)). POSTs use the request body while GETs use the query string. Note that security-wise, this also means important client information isn't blatantly displayed in the URL -- which is *especially* important when dealing with payments.

Update: *Apparently, POSTs *can* use the query string, but they really shouldn't. [See this SO post for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876809/does-post-method-send-data-as-querystring).

Answer (score 0):

[image: paypal ipn]

Yes, order is significant here. This is what I'm going to use:

```
newParameteres = 'cmd=_notify-validate&' + self.request.POST.urlencode()
req = urllib2.Request("http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", newParameteres)
```

Comment: urllib2 is not part of Python3. Any change that you know how to achieve this today? I am having the same struggle right now...

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you access the url below:

```
https://example.com/?fruits=apple&meat=beef
```

Then, you can get all the parameters in `views.py` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563056/how-to-get-all-url-parameters-with-request-get-in-django/77129326#77129326) explains how to get `GET` request values in Django:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):

    print(list(request.GET.items())) # [('fruits', 'apple'), ('meat', 'beef')]
    print(list(request.GET.lists())) # [('fruits', ['apple']), ('meat', ['beef'])]
    print(request.GET.dict()) # {'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'}
    print(dict(request.GET)) # {'fruits': ['apple'], 'meat': ['beef']}
    print(request.META['QUERY_STRING']) # fruits=apple&meat=beef
    print(request.META.get('QUERY_STRING')) # fruits=apple&meat=beef

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```