# How to get all GET request values in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, get, url-parameters

How can I get all of those url parameters (1, 12-18, 5,Happy birthday) in Django?

```
https://domain/method/?1='12-18'&5='Happy birthday'
```

I have tried:

```py
parameter = request.GET.get("1", "")
```

But I only get 12-18.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter is `5`, so you access `'Happy birthday'`:

```
request.GET.get('5', '')
```

note that the strings here will contain the single quotes (`'…'`) as *content* of the string. So normally this should be done *without* quotes.

You can get a list of key-value pairs with:

```
>>> dict(request.GET)
{'1': ["'12-18'"], '5': ["'Happy birthday'"]}
```

This will use the keys as keys of the dictionary, and maps to a *list* of values, since a single key can occurs multiple times in the querystring, and thus map to multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you access the url below:

```
https://example.com/?fruits=apple&meat=beef
```

Then, you can get all the parameters in `views.py` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-request-get-in-django/77129172#77129172) explains how to get `GET` request values in Django:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):

    print(list(request.GET.items())) # [('fruits', 'apple'), ('meat', 'beef')]
    print(list(request.GET.lists())) # [('fruits', ['apple']), ('meat', ['beef'])]
    print(request.GET.dict()) # {'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'}
    print(dict(request.GET)) # {'fruits': ['apple'], 'meat': ['beef']}
    print(request.META['QUERY_STRING']) # fruits=apple&meat=beef
    print(request.META.get('QUERY_STRING')) # fruits=apple&meat=beef

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Then, you can get all the parameters in `index.html` as shown below:

```html
{# "index.html" #}

{{ request.GET.dict }} {# {'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'} #}
{{ request.META.QUERY_STRING }} {# fruits=apple&meat=beef #}
```