# Playframework POST parameter

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to go something really simple with Playframework Scala (2.3): create a route POST and get POST parameters.

The route definition

```
POST    /ff/user                controllers.Application.createUser
```

The controller

```
def createUser = Action.async { request =>
    val user = request.queryString.get("user").flatMap(_.headOption)
    val email = request.queryString.get("email").flatMap(_.headOption)
    val firstname = request.queryString.get("firstname").flatMap(_.headOption)
    val lastname = request.queryString.get("lastname").flatMap(_.headOption)

    Logger.debug("Create User")
    Logger.debug(s"user=$user")
    Logger.debug(s"email=$email")

    Ok("Youpi")
}
```

When I post a request to /ff/user, the log says : user=None, email=None.
I cannot figure out why they are "None". What is wrong?

Thank for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `POST` like this, you probably want to look at the `body` field on the `request` parameter, which will contain the form that was posted.  You usually don't use a query string with `POST` requests (more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876809/does-post-method-send-data-as-querystring)). So, that might look like:

```
def createUser = Action.async { request =>
    val user = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get.get("user").head
    Future(Ok())
}
```

You might also want to use the `Action.async` overload that provides a parsed body.  For example, it might look like:

```
def createUser = Action.async(parse.urlFormEncoded) { request =>
   //body is already treated as a Map[String, Seq[String]] because of the parameter passed to async
   val user = request.body("user").head 
   Future(Ok())
}
```