# How to read a value in WebAPI sent via WebClient.UploadString?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to POST data to WebAPI. Ideally I would just do:

```
http:www.myawesomesite.com?foo=bar
```

As a POST. But to my specific question, I am trying to use:

```
using(var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    client.uploadString("http:www.myawesomesite.com", "POST", "foo=bar");
}
```

[But that converts "foo=bar" to a bye array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0d3595k(v=vs.110).aspx). Okay fine, I'm just trying to get it to work at this point.

My Web API controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void MashPotatos(string foo)
{
    potatoMasher.Mash(foo);
}
```

But I get `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.` First off, I thought WebAPI would automatically grock that data for me even if it was in the body of the request. But more importantly, I just want to be able to get it to work.

Ideally, I'd like to leave the WebAPI method in a form such that you can still invoke it by using a query string with a POST verb.

Comment: You have to configure the routing. All of this fails without even looking at the parameters you try to pass (values in the URL for a POST? Really?)

Comment: That's not a good idea? I liked it because it's simpler.

Answer (score 1):

you need to configure your web API route to accept a foo parameter.May be this will solve your issue

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "newont",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{foo}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Controllername", foo= "foo"}
            );
```

Comment: If I don't use a query string do I still need to use this? No, right? But it's still not working. Query string is ideal but I can skip it.

Comment: 404 error may be Some error will be in your urI https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0d3595k(v=vs.110).aspx from this method will work once you change the route config and check your uri

Answer (score 0):

Well [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API) is a post that might be helpful to some. For me I just had to do:

```
using(var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    client.uploadString("http:www.myawesomesite.com", "POST", "foo=bar");
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public void MashPotatos([FromBody]string foo)
{
    potatoMasher.Mash(foo);
}
```

I decided against doing a POST with a query string as it seems to go against [convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876809/does-post-method-send-data-as-querystring) but there is also a [FromUri] attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetData(){
string jsonResponse = string.Empty;using (WebClient client = new WebClient()){client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
  jsonResponse = client.UploadString(baseuri, "POST", @"{personId:""1"", startDate:""2018-05-21T14:32:00"",endDate:""2018-05-25T18:32:00""}");  
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(jsonResponse);}}
```

> @"{personId:""1"",
>   startDate:""2018-05-21T14:32:00"",endDate:""2018-05-25T18:32:00""}

It's a JSON custom string, or you can serialize the object here on the API side

**HttpPost**

```
    public string Metod(Something data)
    {
        DateTimeOffset sDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(data.date1);
        DateTimeOffset eDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(data.date2);
        return _someService.GetService(data.Id, sDate, eDate);
    }
```

Then we go to the service and get data from DB