# MVC/Javascript: how to post an array of integers in a form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Before doing a form submit for my MVC webpage, I want to see a list of key fields to the controller. However the parameter on the controller is null.
My JavaScript is as follows;

```
   $("#savePropertiesToBeAssigned").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $propertyIds = $("#propertyRows").find($(".selectProperty:checked"));
        var propertyIds = [];
        $.each($propertyIds, function () {
            var propertyId = $(this).data("msurvey-property-id");
            propertyIds.push(propertyId);
        });

        var $form = $(this).closest("form")[0];
        $form.action += "?PropertyIds=" + propertyIds + "&page=" + GetHiddenField("msurvey-page");
        $form.submit();
    });
```

The MVC Action is;

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddFromContract(int[] PropertyIds, int? page)
    {
        var pageNumber = page.GetValueOrDefault(1);
        return RedirectToAction("AddFromContract", new { page = pageNumber });
    }
```

The PropertyIds comes through wrongly as null, whilst the page has the correct value.
EDIT - I am displaying the View in response to a comment:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add properties from the contract into the survey";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddFromContract", "PropertySurvey", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="hiddenFields"
         data-msurvey-page="@ViewBag.Page"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="propertyIds" name="propertyIds" />
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@ViewBag.Title</legend>
        @if (ViewBag.PagedList.Count > 0)
        {
            <section id="PropertyList" style="margin-right: 28px;">
                <p>
                    The properties below have already been added to the contract <b>@SessionObjectsMSurvey.SelectedContract.ContractTitle</b>, but are NOT in this survey
                    <b>@SessionObjectsMSurvey.SelectedContract.SurveyTitle.</b>
                </p>
                <table class="GridTbl">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>UPRN</th>
                        <th>Block UPRN</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            Select All<br/>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"/>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right;">Select the properties you want to include in the survey, and click on the Save button.</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">
                            <button id="savePropertiesToBeAssigned" class="btn-mulalley">
                                Save
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody id="propertyRows">
                    @foreach (var property in ViewBag.PagedList)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@property.UPRN</td>
                            <td>@property.BlockUPRN</td>
                            <td>@property.Address</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <input type="checkbox"
                                       name="selectProperty"
                                       class="selectProperty"
                                       data-msurvey-property-id="@property.PropertyId"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList) ViewBag.PagedList, page => Url.Action("AddFromContract", new {page}))
            </section>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>Either no properties have been entered, or all of them have been assigned to the survey.</p>
        }
    </fieldset>
}
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/page/propertyTransfer")
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you work with `hidden` input elements?

Comment: As @MinusFour says, you should place them in named inputs (hidden or not). [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876809/do-http-post-methods-send-data-as-a-querystring) will explain what is going on. Since the Action is an `[HttpPost]`, mvc will be looking at what is after the Http Headers for the data and not the querystring.

Comment: OK, well I tried that. I found I have to convert the array into a comma separated string field and use the string type parameter in the controller method for this to work - which it did. Of course I can now split the string and I have my array back again. The question is; is this the best way to do this? The problem appears to be to do with posting an array of integers rather than whether I use a hidden field.

Comment: Why don't you send the them using jQuery AJAX?

Comment: If you want to bind to `int[] PropertyIds` then your query string needs to be  `?PropertyIds=someIntValue&PropertyIDs=anotherIntValue&etc`. But this code makes no sense. Why are you creating a query string to a POST method. What are you trying to do? And what is the element with `class="selectProperty"`? None of this code should be necessary if your view is setup correctly. Perhaps showing your view would lead to getting the correct answer.

Comment: I am now showing the View as requested. I am always keen to do the right thing, I was not aware that you should never use a querystring for a Post method. I am not doing that now anyway, I am now using a hidden field as suggested by MinusFour. As a result I have got it working now, but the array of integers is not accepted in the method, I always get null. So instead the parameter is a comma separated string which I convert as follows: var propertyIdList = propertyIds.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList<int>(); Is this the best way to fix this?

Comment: @arame3333, Have just seen your edit. If you were to use hidden inputs as per MinusFour's suggest, then you need one for each row (but it needs to be a `for` loop not a `foreach loop so that the `name` attribute is correctly generated with indexers (and you don't need any script at all.

Comment: But its unclear what your trying to do. You already have an input (checkbox) in each row and you could easily set the value attribute to `value="@property.PropertyId"` which would post back the `PropertyId` values of all selected checkboxes (again without any scripts). Whats unclear is that you script is currently getting the `PropertyId` value for all checkboxes (whether checked or not) which you already know on the server (so what is the point?)

Comment: Apologies. I have just edited the code which was missing the check to find out if the checkboxes have been checked. I am not aware of the value attribute for the checkbox, I will try that next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for any javascript to solve this. You already have checkbox elements in you form, and if they have the correct `name` and `value` attributes, they will bind to your model in the POST method.

Delete the `<input type="hidden" id="propertyIds" name="propertyIds" />` and change the the view to

```
@foreach (var property in ViewBag.PagedList)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@property.UPRN</td>
        ....
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="propertyIds" value="@property.PropertyId" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

and delete the script.

When the form submits, the value of all checked checkboxes will be sent to the controller, and because the checkbox has `name="propertyIds"` they will bind to your `int[] PropertyIds` in the POST method.

You will also need to change `<div id="hiddenFields" data-msurvey-page="@ViewBag.Page"></div>` to

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="@ViewBag.Page" />
```

Side note: I recommend you start using view models rather that using `ViewBag`, including a view model for the collection, which would contain properties `int ID` and `bool IsSelected` so that you can strongly type your view to your model.