# My Querystring is not hitting my Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string

Here is my Action Method-

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult GlobalSearch(int searchcategory,string CityName,int? page)
        {
            string categoryName = cobj.GetCategoryNameAsperId(Convert.ToInt32(searchcategory));
            string city = CityName;
}
```

When i am trying to hit my method using query sting its not hitting.

```
http://localhost:6004/Classified/GlobalSearch?searchcategory=2002&cityName=Bangalore&page=2
```

Can any one please help me finding my issue.

[image]

Comment: In the method signature it's named `CityName` and in the querystring it's `city`, update that to `CityName`. Addtionally as a side note you're using a bunch of different casing rules, you should try and stick to one set of rules

Answer (score 1):

Your GlobalSearch is set for [HttpPost]. You need to switch it to [HttpGet]

Comment: But why even though we are posting these data to the server rit??

Comment: Here you can see some more details on the why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876809/do-http-post-methods-send-data-as-a-querystring

Comment: Thanks the issue is [HttpPost].but any how i need to use post attribute.can u please let me know how can we post that.